# How do I make my display blurry?

Tags: display, laptop

This is a weird question, I know. I recently bought a new laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series). My old laptop was a Toshiba, and the screen was grainy, which made everything look a little blurry. At first I didn't like it, but I grew accustomed to it and actually found the slightly blurry screen was easier on my eyes than a crisp screen. I'm wondering if there is a way to purposely blur a screen?

Comment: I don't really know, but I would look in you video drivers UI for a sharpening option and reduce this to make the screen easier on your eyes, also does the laptop its self contain any hardware buttons to adjust the screen settings ?

Comment: Take hairspray =)

Comment: maybe changing resolution...but that has the effect of making everything larger and giving you less room on screen...does your computer have a matte finish or a gloss one on the screen? Also, are you talking about just fonts or everything? If just fonts then you can change the font smoothing to full. I need to look up how but I doubt it would be that difficult depending on your desktop environment and window manager.

Comment: This is not your question but reducing brightness of your screen will help your eyes